# References in a definition

Tags: java, object, reference, field

I'm sitting here with an assignment that I don't quite understand - I hardly think it's that difficult, but I just don't know how to define the definition so that I make a reference to an object.

The assignment asks me to write a definition of a field named tutor that can hold a reference to an object of type Instructor.

I might not understand the question properly, but I'm fairly sure it's a rather easy assignment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what a reference is?

Comment: I might not, no. 
I'm assuming it's some sort of connection between the definition and the object.

Comment: `Instructor tutor;` - in java objects are handled by their reference ("address" in memory), that can be null.

Comment: In Java, you have primitive types, objects and the array. When you create an object and add attributes to it, primitive types are stored in memory as their real values. The array is not an object but it behaves like one, in a sense that when you assign an array or object as an attribute, you don't keep their real values in memory, but just a reference to them. So if you have two attributes referring to the same object, you don't have two copies in memory, but you have a single copy in memory of the object data and both attributes just keep a reference to that object.

Comment: Draw a square on a piece of paper. Draw an arrow to that square. Label the arrow "square". That arrow is now a reference to the square. Draw a second arrow and name it "square2" and you have a second reference to the exact same square. A variable that is not a primitive is basically that arrow. You can have multiple variables/arrows pointing to the exact same object too.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I understand how that works, I think.
I've already done some assignments telling me to draw the connection (or reference) between classes and objects etc. 
I just wasn't certain of how to write it in code, so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's all the assignment, this is the solution:

```
public class MyClass{

    Instructor tutor;

}
```

Comment: Is it really that simple? Cause I've been thinking about that being the solution seeing the assignment tells me to have a field NAMED tutor, and an object of TYPE Instructor. But when I put them up beside eachother like that, it just seemed like nonsense.
It must've been the fact that they both sound like regular names that confused me..

Comment: Strictly speaking, in order to consider tutor a field, this line should be inside a class, but not inside a method. The way you can see it now on the example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, when you create an object, you must have some way of holding on to it or you wouldn't be able to use it. A lot of times we define the reference and assign the value at the same time. What would happen, though, if you wanted to assign it later? Think about the typical creation of an object and what it would look like without doing the assignment, but just the definition.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some sort of insight. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3

The answer you want is in section 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Objects are manipulated through references in Java. To declare a variable that holds a reference you use the syntax

```
NameOfType nameOfVariable;
```

The variable can optionally be initialized with the "null" reference or with a reference to an object.

Comment: Dude! This is a homework assignment. don't just fork over the answer.

Comment: Haha the op will still have to know which is the type and which is the variable.

Comment: Sadly, you make me sound like a retard because it's that simple; but it is in fact the case - I had a hard time figuring this out :P Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to offend. This question is more about understanding the terminology, and you have to see a few examples to get used to it.

Comment: Yeah I agree. And no, you didn't quite offend me; I've already faced that I'm not the brightest at coding. :)